# CFHTTP does not connect over SSL connection?

Tags: http, ssl, coldfusion, keystore, cfhttp

I have just installed an intermediate & primary SSL certificate on my VPS. Everything is working well, except when I make a cfhttp call:

```
<cfhttp url="https://advert.establishmindfulness.com/ad-zone-1/?categoryid=1" method="get" result="adzone" />
<cfdump var="#adzone#" />
```

From https://app.establishmindfulness.com to https://advert.establishmindfulness.com. These 2 subdomains are on the same server, and I am using a wildcard SSL certificate:

*.establishmindfulness.com

That covers all sub domains.

**VPS environment**

**OS:** Windows 2008R2 with IIS7

**Application server:** Lucee 4.5.2.018 final

**Servlet Container:** Apache Tomcat/8.0.28

**Java:** 1.8.0_66 (Oracle Corporation) 64bit

Do I need to install the intermediate.crt & primaryssl.crt into my keystore cacerts? Is this the problem?

I tried just installing the certificate.cer that I grabbed from Internet Explorer, but maybe this is the wrong approach?

I still get the error:

**Error Detail**

```
Unknown host: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 4):

OK. For anyone who comes across this issue, instead of having to spend several hours pulling your hair out, I managed to get the connection to work:

**This is taken from the following link:**

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lucee/BPm8vYdgkPQ

*Thank you Dominic Watson*

I've just tried this and got it working:

1. Log in to Lucee *server* admin and navigate to "SSL Certificates"
2. Enter your host name "establishmindfulness.com" in the Host field (without the quotes)
3. Hit "list" button
4. Hit "install" button

That's it. The cfhttp call started working.